# error code : 80300002, error message : APP is forbidden to send

Tags: android, push, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

error code: 80300002, error message: APP is forbidden to send. I try to act on the push examples, and it occured this problem. I want to push to my phone,how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubleshooting

1. Sign in to AppGallery Connect and check that HUAWEI Push Kit is enabled.
2. If HMS Core Push SDK 2.0 is integrated, remove the backslash () from the escape character in the access token (AT) and then encode the token using UrlEncode.
3. The token does not match the app.
4. Check whether the value of msg type is 1 or 3. Currently, the value 2 is not supported.
5. If HUAWEI Push Kit functions normally in China and result code 80300002 is returned only for devices outside China, you need to enable HUAWEI Push Kit for devices outside China. Find your app, disable HUAWEI Push Kit, and then enable it again. Note that if you wish to enable HUAWEI Push Kit only, upload the APK of your app to HUAWEI AppGallery first (you can save the APK as a draft). Otherwise, you cannot find the app when enabling HUAWEI Push Kit again.
6. Check whether input errors exist in the body of the message sent.
7. Send a test message on HUAWEI Push Kit Console. If the message is received, the fault is caused by API calling.